# FullCalendar - Ajax callback on success

Tags: fullcalendar

I have setup an eventDrop-function in Full Calendar. At the moment it looks something like this:

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
   $.ajax({
url: ajax_url,
type: "POST",
data: {
    id: event.id,
    event_start: moment(event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
    event_end: moment(event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
    action: 'update_jsonevents'
    }
});
}
```

In my PHP I generate the JSON-data. Little example:

```
$array[$i]=array("id"=>$row["event_id"],
             "title"=>$event_title,
             "start"=>date_format($event_start_time, 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'),
             "end"=>date_format($event_end_time, 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'));
echo json_encode($array);
die();
```

In some examples i have found something like:

```
    error: function() {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    },
```

I want to return something like "success" from PHP to JS and call a function then. I think it is called "callback". I don't know how to Setup it. I tried some things, but it didn't work as expected. Does anybody have an working example for this purpose? (PHP and JS)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I will answer my question on my own ...

PHP-Part:

```
echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true'));
die();
```

JS-Part:

```
success: function(){ 
    alert('Success');
}
```